# python pandas histogram to display binning ranges of qcut

Tags: python, pandas, csv, range, binning

i used qcut to bin the data with ranges. But i want to display the output ranges data in pandas histogram.
So, how do i do that?
ps: the data is  collected from a csv file Link:[Csv file link here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lYZqeYH_AtUAUG5947Bd51JXJBrOP5Lp/view?usp=sharing)

i wrote the following codes -

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

dataset = pd.read_csv("datasets.csv")
print(dataset)


qc = pd.qcut(dataset['Active'], q=8, precision=0)
qc_val = qc.value_counts().sort_index()
print(qc_val)
```

The bining ranges output is-

```
(-1.0, 63.0]          5
(63.0, 212.0]         5
(212.0, 827.0]        4
(827.0, 1465.0]       8
(1465.0, 1959.0]      2
(1959.0, 4545.0]      4
(4545.0, 8594.0]      5
(8594.0, 221447.0]    5
Name: Active, dtype: int64
```

So, is there any way to display a histogram from the above bining ranges data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use the `bins` parameter in the histogram function of a Series, like

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lYZqeYH_AtUAUG5947Bd51JXJBrOP5Lp/view?usp=sharing'
path = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id='+url.split('/')[-2]
df = pd.read_csv(path)
df['Active'].hist(bins=8)
```

[image: possible hist]

or with the labels from the `qcut` you can use it like this

```
levels = [f'Level_{i}' for i in range(8)]
df['Active_bins'] = pd.qcut(df['Active'], q=8, precision=0, labels=levels)
df.head()
```

[image: Data with labels]

```
# from https://stackoverflow.com/a/58288640/7752347
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

hatches = ('\\', '//', '..', '**', "!", '$', '^','#')         # fill pattern

for (i, d),hatch in zip(df.groupby('Active_bins'), hatches):
    d['Active'].hist(alpha=0.7, ax=ax, label=i, hatch=hatch)

ax.legend()
```

[image: Patterned hist]

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. I tried it on jupyter online and it runs but in vscode the histogram doesnot show. Do you know any reason?

Comment: Assuming **in vscode** means **in a script**, Adding `plt.show()` at the end of the script should open a popup with the plot image, ref:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575062/how-to-show-matplotlib-plots-in-python)